# Let $X$ be a metric space $\mathcal{G}$ an open subset of $X$ and $F \subset \mathcal{G}$ finite. Show that $\mathcal{G} \setminus F$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a metric space $\mathcal{G}$ an open subset of $X$ and $F \subset \mathcal{G}$ finite. Show that $\mathcal{G} \setminus F$ is open.

Let $x \in \mathcal{G} \setminus F$. This implies that $x \in \mathcal{G}$ but $\mathcal{G}$ was open by the problem statement and thus $\exists r >0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset \mathcal{G}$. So for arbitary $x \in \mathcal{G} \setminus F$ we can find an $r$ for which $B(x,r) \subset \mathcal{G} \setminus F$ so $\mathcal{G} \setminus F$ is open? I'm not sure I got this right is it true that if $x \in \mathcal{G} \setminus F$, then only possible scenario is that $x \in \mathcal{G}$?

Comment: You found a $r>0$  such that $B(x,r) \subset \mathcal G$, but not with $B(x,r)\subset \mathcal G \backslash F$

Comment: $F$ is closed, its complement is open and intersection of two open sets is open .

Comment: I don't think they mentioned anything about the closedness or openess of $F$?

Comment: A finite set $F$ is closed so $F^\complement$ is open. So $G\setminus F = G \cap F^\complement$ is the intersection of two open sets, so open.